# Spring Integration Java DSL Aggregator by Example

Tags: java, spring-integration

Spring Integration 5.x and Java (not XML) DSL here. I have the following object that will be on the message payload:

```
@Data // lombok is used for convenience
public class JobInfo {

    private String trackingId;
    private JobMeta metadata;
    private List<MiniJob> miniJobs;
    // lots of other fields as well (outside of scope)

}

@Data
public class MiniJob {

    private MiniJobStatus status;
    // lots of other fields as well (outside of scope)

}

@Data
public class MiniJobStatus {

    private String label; // ex: RECEIVED, IN_PROGRESS, COMPLETED, FAILED, etc.
    // lots of other fields as well (outside of scope)

}
```

In my integration flow, these `MiniJobs` are created and sent out over various channels/pathways. I need to implement an `Aggregator` that will wait until all of the `MiniJobs` for a given `JobInfo` are received. Once they are all received I need the aggregator to create a new `JobInfo` out of them and send that `JobInfo` along.

**Every `JobInfo` consists of exactly 4 `MiniJobs`.** So I'm thinking that when I create each `MiniJob` earlier in the flow, I could add a `job-info-uuid` header on their respective `Messages`. That way, when the `Aggregator` receives 4 `Messages` that all have matching `job-info-uuid` header values, it uses those 4 messages to create the `JobInfo` from.

Somewhat out of scope for this, but if someone could provide it in their solution I'd be eternally grateful, would be to introduce the concept of a `MiniJob` *expiry*. Meaning if the `Aggregator` doesn't receive all 4 `job-info-uuids` within, say, 24 hours, it will delete/purge them from whatever it uses to store messages that are awaiting aggregation.

I've been pouring over the Aggregator docs and looked at countless examples, but I'm just not seeing the forrest through the trees here. Do I create a `Consumer<AggregatorSpec>` implementation and define all this aggregation logic inside its `accept(...)` method, and then subsequently, add it to my flow like so:

```
.aggregate(myAggregatorSpecConsumer)
```

Or is that the wrong approach? If anyone could use my example above and help me craft that into a working example, even using pseudo-code, I'd appreciate it so much! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, read this doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#splitter.

So, whatever you say about your `List<MiniJob>` is really a splitter feature. And since there is one-to-one relationship between `Message` and its `payload`, you don't need any extra headers like you mention that `job-info-uuid`. The splitter will populate `CORRELATION_ID`, `SEQUENCE_SIZE`, and `SEQUENCE_NUMBER` headers into splitted item when you return your `List<MiniJob>` from `split(Function)`.

Then when you move on into an `Aggregator` section you'll see a mirroring functionality where, by default` the aggregator really consults with those mentioned headers from splitter and collects groups respectively.

What you will need in the end is just a custom:

```
.aggregate(a -> a
            .outputProcessor((group) -> group
```

To be build a new `JobInfo` from a released group.

See a `groupTimeout()` option for those groups which cannot be gathered in time.

There is also a `MessageGroupStoreReaper` to be scheduled externally since you talk about 24 hours: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#reaper

So, in the end what you need is just something like this:

```
                .split(JobInfo.class, JobInfo::getMiniJobs)
                .channel(c -> c.executor(...))
                .handle(...)
                .aggregate(a -> a
                        .outputProcessor((group) -> {
                            List<MiniJob> miniJobs =
                                    group
                                            .getMessages()
                                            .stream()
                                            .map(m -> (MiniJob) m.getPayload())
                                            .toList();
                            ...
                            return new JobInfo();
                        }))
```

Answer (score 0):

groupTimeout works for me injecting a taskScheduler. I declared a bean in  a configuration class:

```
@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler() {
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new TaskSchedulerBuilder().build();
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("threadPoolTaskScheduler ");
    return threadPoolTaskScheduler;
}
```

then i get it in Flow class with @Autowired annotation and inject it into .taskScheduler() aggregationSpec option

```
@Autowired
ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler;
...
return IntegrationFlows.from(MY_CHANNEL)
        .aggregate(aggregatorSpec -> aggregatorSpec
                .groupTimeout(10000L)
                .taskScheduler(this.dequeuerTaskScheduler)
...
```

Hope this can help you